# Prevent WooCommerce from loading full size images on frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, product

I have a lot of uncompressed images in WooCommerce. Is there a way to force WooCommerce to serve `medium` or `large` sizes instead of `full` on the frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a filter for each WC image size. Looks like the one you want is `woocommerce_gallery_full_size`. Check [this page in the docs](https://woocommerce.com/document/image-sizes-theme-developers/#section-4).

Here is the code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gallery_full_size', function( $size ) {
// Here you must return a string corresponding to a registered image size
return 'medium';
} );
```

From what I can tell that is the only WC image size which serves the full image. Here are the other sizes listed in the docs:

- woocommerce_thumbnail
- woocommerce_single
- woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail